# Why is my get_post_meta not properly calling the custom field when attempting to embed a YouTube video?

Tags: post-meta, embed, youtube

I have  added a custom field to 2 posts in order for a non-developer to be able to post a video link from YouTube, and put the embed id in a custom field to be called by the code below. But when I tried to execute it I get "An error occurred, please try again later." Upon inspection I find that it is trying to call the link as "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Array" instead of filling in the youtubeId.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta(93,'youtubeId');?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

There is the code I am trying to run in a `<div>` in order to embed a YouTube link dynamically. Basically it is a lot easier for my non-developer content managers to edit a Wordpress post with an updated video than go changing the link in the actual page PHP/HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `get_post_meta` returns an array. If you wish to return a single value you need to set the 3rd parameter to `true`.

Eg.

```
get_post_meta(93, 'youtubeId', true);
```

And did you know that your client can just paste a youtube URL into the Wordpress editor and it will auto-embed that video?

[get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: Thank you that was it. No client here. Just me and my gaming community.  I know I can embed in the posts but I want to embed on the home page so this was the best way to do it that I could figure out. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.